# Refactor this: Generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have a extension method that checks the object for its type and then populate its member property

```
public static void LoadMeeting<T>(this T entity, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) 
where T: MyEntity
            {
                var agenda = entity as Agenda;

                if (agenda != null)
                {
                    agenda.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(agenda.MeetingId);
                }

                var participant = entity as Participant;

                if (participant != null)
                {
                    participant.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(participant.MeetingId);
                }

            }
```

can I further refactor that to something like this to make it more generic?

```
 public static void LoadMeeting<T>(this T entity, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) where T : MyEntity
        {
            var obj = entity as Agenda || entity as Participant;

            if (obj != null)
            {
                obj.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(obj.MeetingId);
            }
        }
    }
```

PS: I don't want to put the object's property `Meeting` in the Base class (MyEntity)

Comment: Perhaps you could define an IMeetingEntity interface, which has the MeetingId and Meeting properties.

Comment: Is it possible to do that on Entity Framework 5?, I'm using EF T4 template to generate entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would, personally, just use overloads:

```
public static void LoadMeeting(this Agenda agenda, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) 
{
    if (agenda != null)
    {
         agenda.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(agenda.MeetingId);
    }
}
public static void LoadMeeting(this Participant participant, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) 
{
    if (participant != null)
    {
        participant.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(participant.MeetingId);
    }
}
```

You couldn't do it with a single generic method unless you had some shared contract (either a base class or interface implemented) which provided the `Meeting` property.

The alternative would be to make a shared interface, ie: `IMeeting`, then constrain to that:

```
public interface IMeeting
{
   public Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
   public int MeetingId { get; }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public static void LoadMeeting<T>(this T entity, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository)
```

where T: IMeeting
            {
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    entity.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(entity.MeetingId);
                }
            }

As you're using EF, you could implement this interface in a partial class:

```
public partial class Agenda : MyEntity, IMeeting
{
}
```

Comment: This is actually my first approach, I thought I could use generics to simplify it because this could potentially grow to 100 LoadMeeting methods.

Comment: @LincAbela If you added an interface (ie: `IMeeting`) that these implemented, you could constrain to that, and it would work.

Comment: Is it possible to do that on Entity Framework 5?, I'm using EF T4 template to generate entities

Comment: @LincAbela Yes - they should be partial classes, so you can add code to them. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5044596/65358

Comment: What I just did is put a base entity accross the EF Entities http://fairwaytech.com/2013/09/using-a-common-base-class-across-entity-framework-database-first-entities/

Comment: Ah yeah! I already have partial classes, my first impression was both the partial class instance (the t4 generated and the 'customized') should inherit the same Interface... I will try  it

Answer (score 1):

You may want to return early out of the method incase you have to handle a class and it's base class.

```
public static void LoadMeeting<T>(this T entity, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) where T: MyEntity
        {
            var agenda = entity as Agenda;

            if (agenda != null)
            {
                agenda.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(agenda.MeetingId);
                return;
            }

            var participant = entity as Participant;

            if (participant != null)
            {
                participant.Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(participant.MeetingId);
                return;
            }
        }
```

You might also consider a table approach:

```
    public static void LoadMeeting<T>(this T entity, IMeetingRepository meetingRepository) where T: MyEntity {
        var name = entity.GetType().Name;
        if (Table.ContainsKey(name)) {
            Table[name](entity, meetingRepository);
            }
        }
```

Where Table is:

```
static Dictionary<String, Action<MyEntity, IMeetingRepository>> Table = new Dictionary<String, Action<MyEntity, IMeetingRepository>>();
```

And it is initialized like so:

```
        Table.Add("Agenda", (agenda, meetingRepository) => { 
            ((Agenda)agenda).Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(((Agenda)agenda).MeetingId); }); 
        Table.Add("Participant", (participant, meetingRepository) => { 
            ((Participant)participant).Meeting = meetingRepository.GetMeetingById(((Participant)participant).MeetingId); });
```

Obviously your Table will have to be static and available to your extension method (say in the containing class).