# Creating a generic function in c# that only works with specific types

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

I am trying to create a Generic function that handles either of my 2 models. Note that both of these models have the same exact properties...

For example, in the below code the intellisense has no idea that there is a property called Price in T even though both 'NewProduct' and 'OldProduct' have this property. How can I specify to VS the two Types that I want to be able to pass in? `IList<NewProduct>, IList<OldProduct>`

```
public static IList<T> GenericFunction<T>(IList<T> objList)
{
    IList<T> filteredData = objList.Where(p => p.Price > 0));
}
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965580/c-sharp-generics-syntax-for-multiple-type-parameter-constraints is wrong duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174104/c-sharp-generic-passing-different-objects-with-same-properties could be better, but it asks about queryable (also answer Interface/dynamic applies to this case...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both types need the same interface or common base class, called here `ProductBase`. You can then use a generic constraint with the `where` keyword:

```
public static IList<T> GenericFunction<T>(IList<T> objList) 
  where T : ProductBase
{
    IList<T> filteredData = objList.Where(p => p.Price > 0));
}
```

This works, if `ProductBase` defines a property `Price`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work, you need either a common base class or a common interface implemented in both product types.

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add a [generic type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx):

```
public static IList<P> GenericFunction<P>(IList<P> objList)
    where P : IProduct // Here you can specify either the base class or the interface.
{
    return objList
        .Where(p => p.Price > 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

Now C# knows that the generic type `P` has `Name` and `Price` properties.

---

Note: Instead you could just type the parameter list and the return type as `IList<IProduct>`; however, `IList<OldProduct>` and `IList<NewProduct>` are **not** assignment compatible with it.

---

**UPDATE:** You can instantiate a generic type, if it has a default constructor (i.e. a constructor with an empty parameter list or no explicit constructor declaration at all). You then need to add `new()` to the generic type constraints:

```
where P : IProduct, new()
```

You can then simply create a new object with:

```
P newObject = new P();
```

Comment: You should remove `public` from your interface declaration. Interfaces do not declare their members' access level and any class that implements this interface will always need to declare the members as public. Interface == Contract.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank you for clearing this up for me. All of what you said makes sense. I ran across a scenario where I need to instantiate a new object of P inside of this function. Doesn't this restrict me to using a Generic function like you posted above? Or could I still make it work with a simple function that returns IList<IProduct>? I feel like since I need to instantiate a new object of P and then add it to the return value isn't a Generic function with InterfaceorBaseClass my only option here?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes To clarify my previous comment: I noticed that I have to do something like: P ret = (P)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(P)); in order to instantiate a new object of P and add it to my IList<P> retVal? Does this require me to use a Generic function? I don't believe there are any other workarounds are there?

Comment: I added an explanation on how to instantiate a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the where generic constraint https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

You need some common base class or interface that they both extend/implement. You can define multiple constraints but they must be related.

```
interface IProduct
{
    double Price { get; }
}

public static IList<T> GenericFunction<T>(IList<T> objList) where T : IProduct
{
    IList<T> filteredData = objList.Where(p => p.Price > 0));
}
```

Comment: This is starting to make sense to me now, and I believe this is the correct answer. But if I use an interface there is no point in making a generic function correct? Just make a function that accepts my interface. Make sense?

Comment: Not necessarily true, what's good about this is that the return value is of the actual type (e.g. List<NewProduct>). Using just an interface will always return List<IProduct>.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an interface for this.  Create an interface with the properties that you need:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Color { get; set; }
}
```

These properties should be the ones that your models share.  Then in your model you must implement the interface:

```
public class MyModel : MyInterface
```

Then make your method:

```
public void MyFunction(List<MyInterface> myModel)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into abstract classes, extensions, and polymorphism. Make an abstract class with a price variable then extend your two classes from it. Then use the abstract class as a parameter.

Comment: What about an Interface that both models implement from?

Comment: That works too. See @ventiseis answer